# Is it possible for a python function to ignore unused kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

If I have a simple function:

```
def add(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
```

Is it possible for me to make it so that if I supply an unused kwarg, it is simply ignored?

```
kwargs = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
print add(**kwargs) #prints 6
```

Comment: I think that's the purpose of `**kwargs`...

Comment: Duplicate: [How does one ignore unexpected keyword arguments passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515595/how-does-one-ignore-unexpected-keyword-arguments-passed-to-a-function) [Newer, but has more detailed answers.]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sure. Just add `**kwargs` to the function signature:

```
def add(a, b, c, **kwargs):
    return a + b + c

kwargs = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
print add(**kwargs) 
#prints 6
```

Comment: `**_` to follow convention for unused bindings, and to pass pylint