# How to ignore unexpected keyword argument(s) passed to functions in Python

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

My question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515595/how-does-one-ignore-unexpected-keyword-arguments-passed-to-a-function), however the `**kwargs` solution there isn't working for me.

Let's say I have some functions as shown below. `func_a` prints the values of `arg1` and `arg2`. `func_b` prints the values of `arg1` and `arg3`. So `arg1` is common to both functions. I now have a function, `func`, that calls both `func_a` and `func_b`. In the arguments to `func` I want to be able to pass `arg1`, with `arg2` and `arg3` as optional arguments, hence why I set `arg2` and `arg3` to `None` by default. However, when I try to call `func(arg1='how', arg2='are')` I get an `unexpected keyword argument` error. How can I fix this?

```
def func_a(arg1, arg2=None):
    print(arg1)
    if arg2 is not None:
        print(arg2)

def func_b(arg1, arg3=None):
    print(arg1)
    if arg3 is not None:
        print(arg3)

def func(arg1, **kwargs):
    func_a(arg1, **kwargs)
    func_b(arg1, **kwargs)

# Try to call func
func(arg1='how', arg2='are')
how
are
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-372fbc7b1e90> in <module>
----> 1 func(arg1='how', arg2='are')

<ipython-input-8-5edc2a4c5bfd> in func(arg1, **kwargs)
     11 def func(arg1, **kwargs):
     12     func_a(arg1, **kwargs)
---> 13     func_b(arg1, **kwargs)

TypeError: func_b() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg2'
```

Comment: Just add `**kwargs` to both `func_a` and `func_b`, maybe?

Comment: Why not just extract the relevant data for each in `func`? Broadly passing all the data everywhere seems messy.

Comment: Python functions are strict about there function signatures, although, you are allowed to write a signature which will pretty much accept anything, i.e. `def func(*args, **kwargs)`. The way you've written your functions, though, they will complain if you pass the incorrect arguments, **which is a good thing**

Comment: You're not passing arg3 to func() in your example, that's why func2 can't access it.

Comment: "the **kwargs solution there isn't working for me." needs to be explained further. What did you try? What did not work?

Comment: Also, you have a func2 causing this issue which is not visible in your example code.

Comment: I removed the reference to func1 and func2. Those were erroneously in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to drop blindly arg3 in func_a and arg2 in func_b by allowing them with kwargs but then ignoring them it seems.

```
def func_a(arg1, arg2=None, **kwargs):
    ...

def func_b(arg1, arg3=None, **kwargs):
   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`kwargs` is just a dict of function arguments, so you could just use `get` to get the relevant arguments for each function, which will return `None` if they aren't found:

```
def func_a(arg1, arg2=None):
    print(arg1)
    if arg2 is not None:
        print(arg2)

def func_b(arg1, arg3=None):
    print(arg1)
    if arg3 is not None:
        print(arg3)

def func(arg1, **kwargs):
    func_a(arg1, arg2=kwargs.get("arg2"))
    func_b(arg1, arg3=kwargs.get("arg3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func_a(**kwargs):
    for key,value in kwargs.items():
        if key=='arg1':
            print(value)
        if key=='arg2' and value!=None:
            print(value)

def func_b(**kwargs):
    for key,value in kwargs.items():
        if key=='arg1':
            print(value)
        if key=='arg3' and value!=None:
            print(value)

def func(**kwargs):
    func_a(**kwargs)
    func_b(**kwargs)

# Try to call func
func(arg1='how', arg3='are')
```