# How to use dictionary keys as function variable names?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, variables

I am writing code with multiple functions where most of the functions include the same variables. I have provided some example functions below.

```
# First sample function 
def cg2RollAxisHeight(z_frc, z_rrc, l_w, x_cg, z_cg):
    theta = np.arctan((z_rrc-z_frc)/l_w)
    z_axis = np.tan(theta)*l_w*x_cg
    return z_cg-(z_axis + z_frc)

# Second Sample function
def FrontLateralWT(W, l_w, t_f, K_phiF, K_phiR, A_Y, z_frc, z_rrc, x_cg, z_cg):
    H = CG.cg2RollAxisHeight(z_frc, z_rrc, l_w, x_cg, z_cg)
    b = l_w-(l_w*x_cg)
    return A_Y*W/t_f*(H*K_phiF/(K_phiF+K_phiR)+b/l_w*z_frc)
```

I would like to be able to define all variables and variable names in a single object (e.g. a dictionary) and be able to have my functions pull the required variables needed from that object.

I have tried using **kwargs in the following manner:

```
def cg2RollAxisHeight(**kwargs):
    theta = np.arctan((z_rrc-z_frc)/l_w)
    z_axis = np.tan(theta)*l_w*x_cg
    return z_cg-(z_axis + z_frc)

kwargs = {'W': 180, 'l_w': 2.4, 't_f': 1540, 'K_phiF': 78000, 'K_phiR': 46000,
          'A_Y': 2.5, 'z_frc': 25, 'z_rrc': 60, 'x_cg': .6, 'z_cg': .4}

test = cg2RollAxisHeight(**kwargs)
print(test)
```

The issue here is that the function does not recognize the key as the variable name. Is there a way to use the dictionary key as the variable name within the function? Or is there a better way to do what I am after? I want to avoid using a list because the function would be nearly impossible to decipher.

```
def cg2RollAxisHeight(params):
    theta = np.arctan((params[7]-params[6])/params[1])
    z_axis = np.tan(theta)*params[1]*params[9]
    return paramms[10]-(z_axis + params[6])

params = [180, 2.4, 1540, 78000, 46000, 2.5, 25, 60, 0.6, 0.4}

test = cg2RollAxisHeight(params)
print(test)
```

While the above solution does work, it isn't a neat solution and I would have to do the same to many other much larger functions. Not ideal! Is there a way to create a single object that can be passed to multiple functions without editing the main body of the function?

Comment: It would have to be `kwargs['z_cg']`…?!

Comment: Probably the better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26515595/476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I made your code work:

```
import numpy as np

zeDict = {'W': 180, 'l_w': 2.4, 't_f': 1540, 'K_phiF': 78000, 'K_phiR': 46000,
          'A_Y': 2.5, 'z_frc': 25, 'z_rrc': 60, 'x_cg': .6, 'z_cg': .4}

def cg2RollAxisHeight(myDict):
    theta = np.arctan((myDict['z_rrc']-myDict['z_frc'])/myDict['l_w'])
    z_axis = np.tan(theta)*myDict['l_w']*myDict['x_cg']
    return myDict['z_cg']-(z_axis + myDict['z_frc'])


test = cg2RollAxisHeight(zeDict)
print(test)
```

Seems to me that your approach may suffer from unnecessary complexity in the long run. I suggest using classes.

```
import numpy as np

class cg2:
  def __init__(self):
    # Please, initialize properly
    self.W = 180
    self.l_w = 2.4
    self.t_f = 1540
    self.K_phiF = 78000
    self.K_phiR = 46000
    self.A_Y = 2.5
    self.z_frc = 25
    self.z_rrc = 60
    self.x_cg = .6
    self.z_cg = .4

  def RollAxisHeight(self):
    theta = np.arctan((self.z_rrc-self.z_frc)/self.l_w)
    z_axis = np.tan(theta)*self.l_w*self.x_cg
    return self.z_cg-(z_axis + self.z_frc)
    
  def update(self):
    # Code that updates your parameters goes here
    pass

cg2obj = cg2()
test = cg2obj.RollAxisHeight()
print(test)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try globals()[your_dictionary.keys[index_of_the_key]]
globals()[ ] returns the string in the [ ] as a variable name
[https://www.pythonpool.com/python-globals/#:~:text=Python%20globals()%20function%20is,the%20global%20scope%20actually%20contains.](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-globals/#:%7E:text=Python%20globals()%20function%20is,the%20global%20scope%20actually%20contains.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).